# Does "$a_k>0 \land\sum a_k$ converges $\implies \sum a_k^2$ converges" remain true if the $a_k$ aren't required to be positive?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: Proving of convergent series]

If the phrase "a series of Positive terms" is omitted from the question, I am guessing that the statement will then be incorrect. But I can't think of any counter-examples. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Please type out images. It helps other find this post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As your proof shows, the statement remains true if $\sum a_k$ merely converges *absolutely* (even if the $a_k$ aren't positive). But with the hypothesis of mere convergence there are counterexamples, as the answer below shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the case :

$$\forall n\ge1,\,a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$$

The (alternate) series $\sum_{n\ge1}a_n$ converges, but the (harmonic) series $\sum_{n\ge1}a_n^2$ diverges.

Comment: Hi Adren! Thank you for your reply. I did think of that example you quoted but couldn't decide if the series converges. Does it converge because 1/sqrt(n) strictly decreases to 0 and hence the alternating series will converge too?

Comment: @abc123: Yes, exactly. Except that it is sufficient for the sequence to decrease (even not *strictly*).

Comment: @Adren And also be bounded below.

Comment: @Diego: Of course. A sufficient condition for the series $\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^na_n$ to converge is that the sequence $(a_n)$ is decreasing and has limit $0$ (which implies that it is bounded from below by $0$). I was insisting on the word **strictly**, which can be removed.